# How can I see the current git branch on Xcode9?

Tags: xcode, git, version-control, branch, xcode9

In Xcode 8, the current branch was visible under the 'Source Control' menu. Xcode 9 has a new 'Source Control Navigator'. But you have to scroll (or expand the folder structure) to see the branch that is marked as (current). Is there an easier and probably faster way to know what my current git branch is on Xcode 9?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Navigate to Source Control navigator (the second item on the left sidebar). You will see the name of the current branch next to the project folder's name (in this case, **dev**).

[image: Source Code navigator]